# f:setPropertyActionListener setter not being invoked

Tags: jsf, icefaces, commandlink, icefaces-1.8

I'm using `Icefaces 1.8.2` with `jsf 1.1` 
The setter method of target field is not invoked before the `commandLink` action method.

```
<ice:panelSeries id="deptSeries" value="#{sessionScopedBean.deptList}" var="dept">
......
 <ice:commandLink actionListener="#{myActionBean.search}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{sessionScopedBean.searchList}" 
                                              value="#{dept.myList}"/>
    <ice:graphicImage title="search" url="/images/search.gif"/>
    <f:param name="user" value="#{userBean.name}"/>
 </ice:commandLink>
......
</ice:panelSeries>
```

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `<setPropertyActionListener />` was introduced in JSF 1.2.

Secondly, the code `actionListener="#{myActionBean.search}"` represents an action **listener**, and not an action. Consequently, the method `myActionBean.search()` is called in the same phase of the JSF lifecycle as the property action listener.

Try changing the command link to look like this:

```
<ice:commandLink action="#{myActionBean.search}">
....
</ice:commandLink>
```

This link might be useful to gain an understanding:

[Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)

Comment: I changed to action but there is no difference the setter is still not invoked, the link helped to understand some detail anyway

Comment: Apparently, `<setPropertyActionListener />` was only introduced in JSF 1.2. I updated my answer.

Comment: Great, things like this have to happen, it doesn't complain that I made use of that tag, anyway thank you, let me know if there are any alternatives.